# Unable install angular 2 node modules due to proxy connection setings

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, proxy

I am using Node 8.1.3 and npm 5.0.3. When i Install npm install -g @angular/cli

i am getting connection refused and some proxy errors.I also registered proxy settings in npm registry still i am getting the same proxy connection refused error Please filnd error image as an attachment.

If u are running behind a proxy please make sure that proxy config set properly

How to resolve this issue?

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\System32\npm-debug.log

Comment: There's no such thing as angularjs 2 btw...

Comment: @ William Hampshire when i enter npm install -g @angular/cli through command prompt i am getting below error                                                                                             
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'